# c # Exception index out of range

Tags: c#, exception

```
public class Word
{
    private string _inputWord;
    public Word()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a word");
        _inputWord = Console.ReadLine();

    }

    public void sortandcount()
    {
        char[] test = _inputWord.ToCharArray();
        char temp;
        int count = 0, tcount = 0;
        Array.Sort(test);
        int length = test.Length;
        temp = test[0];

        while (length > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (temp == test[i])
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(temp + " " + count);
                tcount = tcount + count;
                temp = test[tcount]; //this line 
                length = length - count;
                count = 0;
            }
        }



    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main() //this line 
        {
        Word obj = new Word();
obj.sortandcount();
        }
    }
```

i get exception at two lines i have indicated as a comment(as // this line in the program) on that line,, can u people help me to clear abt this. M idea abt the program is to count the number of characters(same) in a given word.
Eg Apple 
a-1
p-2
l-1
e-1

Comment: Try debugging, stepping through your code, and looking at the values for each variable. That should make it fairly easy to figure out the error yourself.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception.aspx. Please note that arrays are zero-indexed, which means the last element index is Length-1.

Comment: @Kjartan sure, i will try that and comment here back, thanks for replying

Comment: @Ram glad to be of help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to output the count of letters in a word, try this code:

```
var testString = "APPLE";

testString.ToCharArray()
.OrderBy(i => i).ToLookup(i => i)
.Select(i => new { letter = i.Key, count = i.Count() }).ToList()
.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("letter {0}, count {1}", i.letter, i.count));
```

This is a bit cleaner and less error prone.

Answer (score 2):

When you've counted all letters then `tcount == test.length` which means that `test[tcount]`will index one element to0 far.

Given any array arr then `arr[arr.length]` will always be out of bounds because the arr is zero indexed. Before temp = test[tcount] you need to ensure that `tcount < test.length` however you also have an error in your logic

try with the word `obo` it will print `o 2 o 2`

a simple implementation of counting the charaters in a word (if the order does not have to be as they appear in the word) would be

```
var result = test.Aggregate(new Dictionary<char,int>(), (state,c)=>{
                if(!state.ContainsKey(c)) { state.Add(c,0); }
                state[c] += 1;
                return state;
             });

foreach(var pair in result) { Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + " " + key.Value); }
```

**EDIT** if you need them to be sorted in the same order as they appear in the word then change the foreach to this

```
foreach(var pair in result.OrderBy(p=>test.IndexOf(p.Key))) {
   Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + " " + key.Value);
}
```

Comment: What if the order should be appeared as same as input

Answer (score 0):

The code contains a bug

```
 int length = test.Length; // This is not zero based
```

and count is zero based, your loop will do one additional iteration causing

```
 temp = test[tcount]
```

to fail because tcount now became bigger than the length of test by 1 character.

The best thing to do is

```
int length = test.Length -1;
```

Please let me know if this helps :) have a nice day

Comment: I just added this if condition , so the one more iteration issue will be solved, and thanks for helping me 

if (tcount!=test.length)
temp = test[tcount];

Comment: Great ^^ I am glad you came out with a solution

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more "programmatic" version:

```
public class Word
{
    private string _inputWord;
    public Word()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a word");
        _inputWord = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void SortAndCount()
    {
        // sort
        char[] array = _inputWord.ToCharArray();
        Array.Sort(array);
        // for all characters
        for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            // duplicate check
            if(i > 0 && array[i] == array[i - 1])
                continue;
            // count
            int count = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
                if(array[i] == array[j])
                    count++;
            Console.WriteLine(array[i] + " " + count);
        }
   }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Word obj = new Word();
        obj.SortAndCount();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is more readable than mine. But using two for loops takes more iteration than required so i went to while.

Comment: @Ram, added duplicate check.